# Want to customize design of bar chart in ag-chart-react

Tags: reactjs, ag-charts-react, ag-charts

I am implementing bar chart using ag-chart in react, I want to do following customization in the chart.

1. want to show vertical axis label on top of each bar, and horizontal axis label on the front of each bar
2. bar corner should be rounded.
   Please help me how we can do this

This is my component

```
'use strict';


import { AgChartsReact } from 'ag-charts-react';

const ChartExample = () => {
    const [options, setOptions] = useState({
        title: {
            text: "Apple's Revenue by Product Category",
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'In Billion U.S. Dollars',
        },
        data: getData(),
        width : 500,
        height  :400,
        padding: {
            top:10
        },
        theme : "ag-vivid",
        series: [
            {
                type: 'bar',
                direction: 'horizontal',
                xKey: 'quarter',
                yKey: 'iphone',
                yName: 'iPhone',
                
            }
        ],           
        
    });
    return <AgChartsReact options={options} />;
};
```